# Increment variable names in visual basic

Tags: visual-studio-2013

It seems that this question has been asked quite a few times, but I am not getting any answers I can clearly understand.  I want to do a very basic simple thing but I can't get an answer.  I am using Visual Studio 2013 & visual basic, I want do this:

```
For i = 1 To 8
     field & i = nothing
    Next i
```

instead of this:

```
field1 = Nothing
field2 = Nothing
field3 = Nothing
field4 = Nothing
Field5 = Nothing
Field6 = Nothing
Field7 = Nothing
Field8 = Nothing
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use an array instead.

```
Dim field(7) As Object

For i As Integer = 0 To UBound(field)
    field(i) = Nothing
Next
```

Edit: Case